# Getting N sorted items from an array of sorted arrays

Tags: java, android, sorting, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have a multidimensional array of dates, strictly an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>>`. I need to generate a new single-dimensional `ArrayList<Date>` made up of the items in all the arrays of the previously mentioned multidimensional one.

My first thought was to join all the arraylists together and sort them, but since I don't know the number of elements in each level, and only need a certain number of elements in the generated array, that would be a bit too much memory-and-processor-heavy.
I mean, if I join all the `Date` elements in one `ArrayList<Date>`, I might end up with an arraylist of thousands of dates... to just eventually trim it to the first 20. That's why I dropped that solution.

So, which algorithm could I use to sort elements from N (or 2) levels into 1?

**Edit**

```
ArrayList<Date> a1 = new ArrayList<Date>();
a1.add(new Date(15));
a1.add(new Date(16));
a1.add(new Date(23));

ArrayList<Date> a2 = new ArrayList<Date>();
a2.add(new Date(1));
a2.add(new Date(25));
a2.add(new Date(89));

ArrayList<Date> a3 = new ArrayList<Date>();
a3.add(new Date(64));
a3.add(new Date(72));
a3.add(new Date(73));

ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>> b = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Date>>();
b.add(a1);
b.add(a2);
b.add(a3);
```

I need to implement a `getLatestDates(ArryList<ArrayList<Date>>, Integer)` such that would return this:

```
getLatestDates(b, 5) = {Date (89), Date(73), Date(72), Date(64), Date(25)};
```

In this example there are only 3 `ArrayList`, but in the practice I won't know the number, so I don't think the best solution for a mobile device is joining all the second level arraylists and sorting the new big one, if only a number of items is to be used.

Comment: `I need to generate...`.  It'll happen only if you **try**.

Comment: Could you be more specific? It sounds like you solved (mentally atleast) it the right way and said that it is not what you want..

Comment: Between the lines, I read that you want the first 20 dates, rather than sorting the whole list. This is a different question, and has a faster solution than sorting. Please be clear in what you want.

Comment: @KarthikT my initial thoughts of a solution are very resource-intensive. If I join all the `Date` elements, I can end up handling a huge array of dates, and actually I only need to use a part of it. That's why I thought I need a more optimised solution.

Comment: @Jago the confusion comes from the fact that your question asks exactly that.. So I expect there are details you are missing out, or the question can be worded better perhaps.

Comment: Ok, edited the question with an example of what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description of the problem, some solutions I can think of are :

1. Ofcourse the one you suggested, i.e. appending all the arrays and then sorting them and taking first 20 of them.
2. Sort each of these inner arrays individually and then do a merge like procedure from merge-sort algorithm to merge first 20 items from all these inner arrays and break out of the merge loop whenever desired number of items are merged(e.g. 20 items).
3. Sort each of these inner arrays while putting dates in them. So that you won't have to iterate through each one afterwords. Then do a merge like procedure as said above.

If you have several items in several inner arrays and you want first 20 out of them then you are going to have to iterate through the inner arrays to sort in some way or another. These are the 3 solutions I can think of, anyone else is welcome to add to my post.

Edit :

4.
One more approach I can think of is : build a priority queue(min heap) by scanning through the entire array of inner arrays. This will be a depth limited tree i.e. since you want 20 elements the max depth of the tree can be 4(assuming root as 0). and max number of allowed items in your heap will be 20. This approach will give you solution in O(log N) time. Ofcourse you will spend O(N) time in scanning every item out of the entire list and building that heap may take up extra space.

Comment: Point 2 sounds quite intreresting. Not a huge array of dates, and not a tournament... seems reasonable...

Comment: Yes, but that approach might do worse if there are many inner arrays with many elements. The only advantage you will have then is worst case time for merge sort is still O(N log N) so its still a win. So choose wisely.

Comment: If you are considering 2), want a solution at fairly low programming expense and feel ok with O(n*logn) complexity, try gathering all your Dates in a TreeMap, which will sort them automatically. Then you can call myTreeMap.firstKey() n times. If you want to remove duplicates, use a TreeSet instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a [tournament algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting#Tournament_Algorithm). This can be pretty complicated, but would give you a running time linear in the *total* number of elements.

I would proceed as follows:

1. Have a tournament per list and store the tournament tree (this tree could be pretty trivial: per element, keep a list of opponents and the result)
2. Have a tournament between the winners and store the tournament tree
3. The first element is the winner of tournament 2
4. The second element is among the losers of the winner in either tournament 1 or tournament 2
5. The third element is among the losers of nr2 in either tournament 1 or tournament 2
6. And so on...

Comment: Sounds quite a good solution. I was just wondering if it could be even more resource-consuming in a mobile device than merging all the elements in a single arraylist and sorting it...?

Comment: @Jago That's a good question. The storage will be `O(n)`, but I'm not quite sure about the constant. And you need a *huge* array before a linear algorithm with bad constants outperforms an `n log n` algorithm  with good constants (such as the default quick sort). Still, you could consider this approach when you hit performance problems because you have very many dates.

Comment: I think this approach consumes too much space and considering it's done in mobile phone its almost not feasible.